# how to find out where a vim highlighting is defined?

Tags: vim, highlighting, color-scheme

I'm trying to change the highlighting in vim for the highlighting group "Folded". I'm using the color scheme "koehler" and my folded lines appear in cyan on a grey background in gvim, which is completely unreadable. 
I thought I could edit the :highlight command responsible for this group in the koehler.vim color scheme file but there is no definition for "Folded" in that file.

I verified that I have color scheme koehler loaded:

```
:echo g:colors_name
koehler
```

Then I listed all the highlighting groups with a command I found in another post:

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim   

Highlighting groups for various occasions
-----------------------------------------
[...]
Folded  Folded
FoldColumn  FoldColumn
[...]
```

The "Folded" group is shown in the ugly colors I also see in my files. The file I was editing was a "viki" file but I get exactly the same with a perl script, so the highlighting for "Folded" must be defined somewhere central. I don't have any :hilight commands in my .vimrc.

How can I find out where this group is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`hitest.vim` doesn't tell you where anything is defined. Just what *is* defined and grouped.)

That looks like it's probably the default setting. You can override it in a colorscheme (the easiest way is to copy `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/koehler.vim` to `~/.vim/colors/koehler.vim` and add the lines), like this:

```
hi FoldColumn      guifg=#465457 guibg=#000000
hi Folded          guifg=#465457 guibg=#000000
```

(That example is taken from the theme I use, [molokai](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2340), which has fairly nice folding colors.)

Comment: Thanks - yes, it seems that that is the best thing to do here. Out of curiosity: where would those defaults be defined?

Comment: Trying Xavier's `:verbose hi Folded`, skipping the vimrc and changing the colorscheme, it claims it's set in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/koehler.vim`, though it's not. I suspect that means it's hard-coded.

Answer (score 17):

Using

```
:verbose hi Folded
```

You should be able to display where the Folded attribute was last modified.
(Usually the answer is the active colorscheme file)